# Como puedo recargar una imagen con ajax despues de subirla

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo que subir una imagen al servidor y mostrarla en la pagina una vez subida, la primera vez funciona todo normal, el problema es que se cachea al volverla a subir y no cambia a menos que se refresque el navegador.
Este es el codigo:

```
$(".post-file").click(function() {
    // Determine which button was pressed //
    editPersonnelBtn = $(this).attr("name");

    $(".ajaxFormUpdate").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mainContent1').html('<div align="center"><img src="assets/images/loading.gif"/></div>');
        var postData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#mainContent1").html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Connection error");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind();
    });
});
```

Y este es el html

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="well">
        <legend class="text-center">Mi firma</legend>
        <form name="ajaxFormUpdate" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ajaxFormUpdate" action="assets/contentHtml/handler-profile-manager.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="formSelector" value="selectSign" />
            <div id="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);">
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5000000" />
                <input name="sign" id="sign" type="file" accept="image/*" required/><small>solo pdf (5MB max)</small><br><br>
            </div><br>
            <button class="btn btn-info post-file btn-profile-manager" name="btw-sign" id="btw-sign">Aceptar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="well">
        <!-- This is where the content is -->
        <div class="text-center" id="mainContent1">
            <img src="<?php echo $ruta ?>" width="50%" heigth="50%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Agrégale al nombre del archivo un valor que cambie cada vez que los subas, por ejemplo un código de sesión o similar, así forzaras a que se actualice

Comment: Te he modificado el código porque había errores de sintaxis.

Comment: Para mostrar la imagen, el PHP que la sube, debería devolver su ruta y nombre y así, en la parte del success del ajax, puedes cargarla sin problemas. Si nos muestras el PHP también, podremos analizar mejor.

Comment: podrias usar este ejemplo: https://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/

Comment: https://cloudinary.com/visualweb/display/IMMC/Image+Upload+Using+Ajax#ajax-image-upload-using-php

Comment: Puedes poner que es lo que trae la variable data en el success?

Comment: Gracias a todos por su ayuda, al final encontre una solucion aqui mismo, puse en el success un dato que cambia con cada request, `$('.pic img').attr('src', 'assets/images/signatures/SIGN_'+empId+'.jpg'  + '?_=' + new Date().getTime());`, y que cada vez que se recarge la pagina con esta funcion `$(document).ready(function(){
                   $(\'.pic img\').attr(\'src\', \'assets/images/signatures/SIGN_\'+empId+\'.jpg\'  + \'?_=\' + new Date().getTime());
                });`, no se si sea la mejor solucion, pero hasta ahorita me funciona todo bien.

Comment: track3r gracias por la correccion de codigo, realmente tengo el html embebido, es por eso los echos, pero gracias.